# Копирование одного символа из одного textbox в другой textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. Не знаю как реализовать такую вещь. Мне нужно чтоб если в textbox1 первым символом стоит минус то его автоматически копировало бы в textbox2. Как это реализовать?

Comment: if (MyTextBox.Text[0] == '-') MyTextBox2.Text = MyTextBox.Text;

Comment: Данная стока полностью копирует textbox1 а мне нужно чтоб именно первый символ копировало

Comment: @Влад  покажете ваше неработающее (пока что) решение? :)

Comment: Здесь по сути три вопроса в одном: (1) как проверить первый символ в строке (2) как добавить символ в строку (3) как изменить содержимое TextBox. Без примера неясно с какой именно частью возникла проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите, я просто объясню вам что к чему.

Для начала, любое `string` значение можно разбить на буквы (`char`). То есть у нас есть к примеру строка `string hello = "World!";`, если мы пройдёмся по ней циклом, что будет? Давайте проверим...

```
string hello = "World!";
foreach (char c in hello)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Хм, на выходе у нас результат будет следующий:

```
W
o
r
l
d
!
```

То есть можно сделать вывод, что `string` уже сам реализует некий интерфейс, который позволяет нам без лишних действий использовать его как некий массив символов. Тогда почему бы нам просто не обратиться к нужному символу (буд то это массив)? Попробуем:

```
string hello = "World!";
Console.WriteLine(hello[0]);
```

Результатом будет:

```
W
```

Ну что, в итоге мы разобрались с тем, как нам получить необходимую букву из строки. Кстати, я к сожалению не знаю, с какой версии языка появилось это все, но как вариант, это разбить строку на символы самому, для этого есть метод `ToCharArray()`. Разбиваем строку на символы, ну и работаем как и раньше:

```
string hello = "World!";
char[] myChars = hello.ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(myChars[0]);
```

Ок, с этим разобрались. Что нам требуется дальше?

> Мне нужно чтоб если в textbox1 первым символом стоит минус то его автоматически копировало бы в textbox2.

Зная как нам из `string` "вытянуть" нужную букву, это теперь становиться довольно простой задачкой. Для начала проверим, на что начинается значение у `textbox1`. Для этого нам понадобиться `if`, предыдущие знания, ну или метод `StartsWith()`.

Напишем с использование полученных выше знаний:

```
if (textBox1.Text[0] == '-')
{
    Console.WriteLine(true);
}
```

После данного кода, наша программа проверит написанный текст на соответсвие первого символа. Если он совпал с заданным нам (в данном случае это `-`), то выводим `True`.

Перепишем тоже самое и используем `StartsWith()`. Что это такое вообще? Это один из хороших помощников, который (`StartWith()` и `EndsWith()`), задача его заключается в сопоставление первого (или последнего) символа/символов. На вход он принимает `string` значение, а на выход выдаст `bool` результат. Попробуем:

```
if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(true);
}
```

Результатом будет тоже, что и в примере ранее.

Хорошо, с проверкой символа вроде разобрались. Теперь решим это:

> мне нужно чтоб именно первый символ копировало

Собрав все, что мы узнали выше, мы можем без труда теперь сделать следующее:

```
if (textBox1.Text[0] == '-')
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text[0].ToString();
}
```

Что здесь происходит? Хм, мы проверили значение в `textBox1` на стартовой символ, если он совпадает, то переносим этот символ в `textBox2`. Так, как `textBox2.Text` - это `string` значение, а символ это `char`, то нам надо перевести из `char` в `string` (что и делает `.ToString()`).

Также момент! Если нам нужно не первый символ, а что то после `-`, то как не трудно догадаться, мы можем его указать, заменив `[0]` на нужное значение!.

И ещё момент!! Перед получением символа, советую сделать проверку на длину, да или хотя бы на `null` значение. Иначе будем получать ошибку. Можно сделать до всех действий что то вроде:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) return;
```

Тут мы проверяем, не пустое ли значение `textBox1.Text`. Если да, то просто прекращаем выполнение данного метода.

Ну, теперь вроде все. Надеюсь помог. Удачи!